# OAuth Merge Local Account With Third-Party

Tags: php, angularjs, facebook, oauth

I'm working with a team on a webapp that will use an existing database with client data, but has no user accounts setup. The goal is to have users perform an email lookup in the database to see if their info already exists, that way if we find them, we can tie the existing data to their new user account.

We'd also like to implement OAuth so that users are able to login via facebook or google, but we're a bit unsure on how to link these third-party accounts to our own. We can request the email back and check it against our DB (assuming the user grants us access), but that would be a big assumption of them having the same email in our system as their other accounts.

Getting to the actual point, we're curious as to how others have implemented this workflow. Would it be better to force the user to check for their email first when selecting one of those options? or roll the dice with a lookup? Should we hide the option to login via third-party and only allow them to associate a third-party account after they login (so they would automatically login to our site assuming they're logged in elsewhere)? Or would it be best to let them build a new account, and provide admin tools to link local data to an account after the fact?

Sorry for the open-ended question, I'm sure I'll get some downvotes here (don't hate me), but I've been scouring the internet for a while with very little to show for it, and I feel that the StackOverflow community is one of the best Q&A resources out there (love you guys).

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have client data - it will be a bad move to force all those users to do something - anything really. So, unless you are cardinally changing way too many things - you must smoothly move them over to the new opportunities in your app.

For the old users - offer to login with their existing account, and offer to add social network (maybe some notice at the top of the window about it), with which they can authenticate afterwards.

For the new users - offer to create an account like old users, and also offer to create account by using oauth.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Toly. The problem is that none of the clients have an account setup locally at this time (we have their info, but there is currently no login functionality anywhere for them). We need some way that if they try to login via a third-party, like facebook, that it doesn't arbitrarily create a new "blank" account for them, but instead is able to create a new account in our system using their existing info.

Comment: Do you have some unique ids? Email? Phone? Social security? Something? 

If it is an email - you can get it from some social networks while using auth (but not all of them). 

If it is not smth easily accessible from the variety of social networks you are going to use - i.e. phone number, but still unique to your existing data - you should create an interface with two-step authentication. In first step - you either create account normal way, or authenticate via social network. In second step - you enter additional data, including that unique phone number. Then connect the data to account.

Comment: We're planning on using email as the unique identifier. I like the idea of two-step authentication. Basically what I think you're saying is to allow them to login to the third-party, and when we get the response, either log them in (if they've already created the account), or have them lookup the email in our system. We can then associate the token with our existing info. Let me know if I'm misunderstanding you.